# T-testing on sparse data

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, t-test, p-value, sparse

**Problem:** I have two stochastic processes, $S_1$ and $S_2$, that frequently are zero, but occasionally have positive values with unknown probabilities $q_1$ and $q_2$. e.g.

$$
S_1 = \{0,0,0,0,0,21,0,0,0,0,\dots,0,0,112,0,0,0,\dots 0,0,47,0,0,0 \} \\
S_2 = \{0,0,0,31,0,0,0,0,0,0,\dots,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,\dots 0,0,0,0,212 \}
$$

I know a probability density function $p(q|S)$ that tells me the probability of $q$ being a certain value.

I have no information that suggests the values of $q_1$ and $q_2$ influence the values of non-zero elements in $S_1$ and $S_2$.

I have no information about the shape of the distribution of the value of non-zero elements in $S_1$ or $S_2$.

I assume the distributions of $S_1$ and $S_2$ are independent and all samples of $S_1$ and $S_2$ are independent.

**Goal:** I wish to test if $S_1$ and $S_2$ have a similar mean.

**Suggested Approach:** I define a function $T(S_1,S_2,\alpha \in \mathbb{R})$ which is equal to the p-value of a two-sided t-test applied to the non-zero elements of $S_1$, and $\tilde{S}_2 = \{\alpha \cdot s \text{ for all }s \in S\}$. This amounts to the p-value of a t-test for the hypothesis that the non-zero elements of $S_1$ have a mean equal to $\alpha$ times the mean of the non-zero elements of $S_2$.

Using this function, I can test for the expectation of the p-value associated with $S_1$ and $S_2$ having the same overall mean by calculating:

$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1 T\left(S_1,S_2,\frac{q_1}{q_2}\right) \cdot p(q_1|S_1) \cdot p(q_2|S_2)dq_1dq_2
$$

Can I then use this expected p-value in place of a normal one? or can I do something like:

$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1 \left(T\left(S_1,S_2,\frac{q_1}{q_2}\right)<0.05\right) \cdot p(q_1|S_1) \cdot p(q_2|S_2)dq_1dq_2
$$

**Question:** Is this approach valid? or am I reaching new and hitherto unexplored levels of stupidity? I feel like a traditional welches t-test will suffer due to the high variances induced by the zero elements and will not take advantage of my possession of a posterior for q.